# Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:2.12.4:test (default-test) on project myserver

Tags: java, neo4j, graphaware

This is my pom.xml file,

```xml
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>neo4j.embedded.myserver</groupId>
<artifactId>myserver</artifactId>
<packaging>jar</packaging>
<properties>
<java.version>1.7</java.version>
<maven.compiler.source>1.7</maven.compiler.source>
<maven.compiler.target>1.7</maven.compiler.target>
</properties>
<version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
<name>myserver</name>
<url>http://maven.apache.org</url>
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.neo4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>neo4j</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.4</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-client</artifactId>
        <version>1.8</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-client</artifactId>
        <version>2.13</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.neo4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>neo4j-kernel</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.4</version>
        <type>test-jar</type>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>4.11</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hamcrest</groupId>
        <artifactId>hamcrest-all</artifactId>
        <version>1.3</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>  
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.graphaware.neo4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>tests</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.5.25</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.assertj</groupId>
        <artifactId>assertj-neo4j</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.0</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.json</groupId>
        <artifactId>json</artifactId>
        <version>20140107</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
</project>
```

And I use eclipse , use run as→maven build , this is my error information,

> Results :
>
> Tests in error: 
>      nodeCreationWithLabel(neo4j.tests.Neo4jTest): org/neo4j/kernel/impl/util/function/Optionals$LazyOptional
>      nodeCreationWithLabel(neo4j.tests.Neo4jTest)
>      compareProperties(neo4j.tests.Neo4jTest): org/neo4j/kernel/impl/cache/HPCSettingFunctions$4
>      compareProperties(neo4j.tests.Neo4jTest)
>      compareNeo4jDatabase(neo4j.tests.Neo4jTest): org/neo4j/kernel/impl/cache/HPCSettingFunctions$4
>      compareNeo4jDatabase(neo4j.tests.Neo4jTest)
>
> Tests run: 6, Failures: 0, Errors: 6, Skipped: 0
>
> [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
>
> [INFO] BUILD FAILURE
>
> [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
>
> [INFO] Total time: 2.838 s
>
> [INFO] Finished at: 2015-10-28T16:14:21+08:00
>
> [INFO] Final Memory: 11M/28M
>
> [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
>
> [ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:2.12.4:test (default-test) on project myserver: There are test failures.
>
> [ERROR]
>
> [ERROR] Please refer to D:\Eclipse\workspace\MyNeo4jSamples\target\surefire-reports for the individual test results.
>
> [ERROR] -> [Help 1]
>
> [ERROR]
>
> [ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
>
> [ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
>
> [ERROR]
>
> [ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
>
> [ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoFailureException

Comment: Can you please add your test code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using Neo4j and GraphAware framework.

GraphAware framework version is coupled with Neo4j version.

Neo4j - 2.2.4
GraphAware Framework - 2.1.5.25 (here is the problem)

You should use version 2.2.4.34 of GraphAware Framework.